# Shell error: redirection unexpected in using bc

Tags: shell, redirect, error-handling, printf, bc

Error is in stroke:

```
printf "%15s\t%5d\t%5.2f%%\n" bc <<< "scale=2; 100 * $mac / $totals" > result
```

i cant understand it. Before bc and after $totals" is sign `

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "%15s\t%5d\t%5.2f%%\n" $(bc <<< "scale=2; 100 * $mac / $totals") > result
                              ^^                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `bc`. The string `bc` is simply the first of 3 expected arguments to `printf`. When your shell recognizes `<<<` as a redirection operator where the 2nd argument to `printf` should be, it throws an error.

I suspect you want `$(bc <<< "scale=2; 100 * $mac / $totals")`, but it's not clear which argument to `printf` that should be (although, it looks like it should be the third, for the `%5.2f` placeholder), or what the other two arguments should be.